# Is the given function a homomorphism? If yes, is it also one to one and onto?

Tags: abstract-algebra

So it has been over a year since I've taken Abstract Algebra and I'm trying to help my friend review for a final he has coming up. This question stuck out on the review and I couldn't remember how to answer it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Let $G$ be the set of positive real numbers under multiplication and let $G'$ be the set of all real numbers under addition. Let $f : G \rightarrow G'$ be the function given by $f(x) = ln(x)$. Is $f$ a homomorphism? If yes, is it also one to one and onto?

Comment: It's not really a question in algebra. Use the properties of the log function to show from defenition that it's homomorphisim

Comment: What has your friend tried.  S/he is currently in the class, and so should be familiar enough with what s/he has studied over the course of this semester.  And if this is a review, s/he surely has some ideas to offer, and has access to the text, the lecture notes, their homework problems...etc.  And then after taking a stab at answering the review question, and s/he has a specific problem to ask about the question, s/he is welcome to post here.  Registering an account here is quickly and easily done, after which s/he can ask about the problem, since you seem to not be helpful.

Comment: This is for a senior seminar course, which is basically a review of all the core math classes that he has taken. He hasn't had Abstract in awhile either.

Answer (score 2):

Yes! This is a very standard question, this will be more of a hint than a full answer. To show that it is a group homomorphism you just need to verify that

$$f(ab) = f(a) + f(b)$$ which is straightforward (note that we use multiplication on LHS and addition on RHS as these are our group operations).

Then for the second part you really need to check that for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ there is $a \in \mathbb{R}^+$ such that $f(a)= x$ which should be straightforward.

Secondly, we need to show $f(a) = f(b)$ implies $a=b$ which again should be straightforward